# "IO error while decoding Routes.scala with UTF-8" when compiling Play Framework project

Tags: scala, playframework

When I compile my project, the console will show:

> [error] IO error while decoding Routes.scala with UTF-8,Please try
>   specifying another one using the -encoding option"

What might be the reason for this error?

Comment: Can you show us your routes file?

Comment: # Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
#登陆
POST   /login                      @controllers.here.backend.Application.login 
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

Answer (score 0):

You might have smart quotes or other Microsoft specific encoded characters in your routes file.  This can often happen if you copy and paste from a Microsoft Word document or from the web into your file.  Look for “ or ” or apostrophe characters that curl one way or another.  Replace them in a programmer's text editor with regular straight quotes and single quotes.